# How to calculate cumulative distibution functions in matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics

How to solve the following problem, not quite sure how to do it, using the MATLAB functions: `binocdf`, `normcdf`, `expcdf`:

This is given:

```
X1 ∈ Bin(10, 0.3), X2 ∈ N(5, 3), X3 ∈ Exp(7)
k = 1, 2, 3
```

What is this probability `P(3 < Xk ≤ 4) = ?`

I know that the cumulative distribution function gives you the probability of a stochastic variable of being less than or equal to the input if you use for example:

```
binocdf(4,10,0.3) = P(X1 ≤ 4)
```

But how do I use these functions when it's `Xk > 3`?

Comment: @tennisfan: Please read the [FAQ about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). We don't do people's work for them here and we can't guess at what you're trying to do (there doesn't even seem to be enough information to fully understand your problem). Show us the code you've tried so far and indicate what is specifically not working.

Comment: Of course I know that it's not a place for just giving answer to other person questions, but I don't understand how to solve the problem and that's why I'm asking, cause I want to learn how to. It's all the info I havde in the problem and more so don't see how it's to little info though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remember the properties of a CDF, you can find the probability of an event of a random variable spanned by an interval `[a,b]` by simply substituting each end point into the CDF and subtracting the two quantities.  Concretely, given `f` being the PDF and `F` being the CDF of a random variable `X`, calculating the probability of the event occurring `P(a < X <= b)` is such that:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)</sup>

Therefore, to compute `P(3 < X1 <= 4)` as for your example, do:

```
out = binocdf(4,10,0.3) - binocdf(3,10,0.3);
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out the other ones.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just had a thought about the importance of <, <= when it comes to discrete or continuous distributions and if that changes the approach when you have some other intervals that just this example. Thinking about this for example:  P(X<48) is really P(X<=47) when it comes to binomial distribution.

Comment: @Tennisfan That's correct.  Therefore, it entirely depends if your distribution is continuous or discrete.  You need to be careful.  In any case, if you no longer need any help, consider accepting the answer to let the SO community know that your issue has been resolved.  Good luck!